# Connect to specific user from STUN server in WEB RTC

Tags: webrtc, stun, peer

I'm trying to achieve peer to peer video conference using google stun server.
I can connect anyone by stun server randomly.Because stun gives multiple and random addresses and connect with it.
But is there any way to connect specific peer by stun server for a login based system or room based system?
I want to achive something like - https://apprtc.appspot.com/

Comment: That room/login based system is handled by the SIGNALLING server and not the STUN server.

Comment: Did you mean SignalR as SIGNALLING server for setting up room based system?Or it's another kind of server like Stun?

Comment: It could be signalR or any number of things you use yo signal but that is the part that sets up rooms and such. The stun server is only for ice candidate gathering and Nat traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your signalling method (this is up to the application developer), which is independent of STUN.

WebRTC does not specify the mechanism for signalling. Signalling is the method whereby users discover each other and establish that a call (media streams between two peers) is going to take place.

The 'discovery' process could involve a registration-based system (eg using SIP proxy) or room based where two users have access to a 'room' (by knowing the credentials or some means of authentication). Once two peers have found each other, their browsers then need to share and negotiate network topology and media capabilities to ensure that the streams can reach the intended destination and can be encoded/decoded properly.